# Ожидание загрузки страницы

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, при открытии страницы выполняется скрипт. Подскажите способы как добавить надпись "пожалуйста подождите" а когда скрипт загрузится показать контент на странице. Вот моя html на что нужно разместить такой скрипт. Какой нибудь простенький. Пример шаблонов таких скриптов найти не смог, может у кого есть.

```
<div class="filemanager">
    <div class="search">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск файлов..." />
    </div>
    <div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
    <ul class="data"></ul>
    <div class="nothingfound">
        <div class="nofiles"></div>
        <span>Нет файлов.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно закрыть необходимые вам или все элементы на странице прелоадером, который будет исчезать после необходимых действий на странице.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {});
    }, 2000);

  });
});
```

```css
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/3.7.0/processing.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader"></div>
<p>EXEMPLE</p>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/593Lqqnm/25/)

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов несколько:

1. С использование jQuery. Код будет выполнен браузером после загрузки всех файлов и рендеринга страницы.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     тут твой код
   });
   ```
2. Реально длительный процесс, который исполняется на сервере. В этом случае клиенту отдается html как в примере.

   ```
    <div class="inprogress">
      Progress indicator
    </div>
   ```

По мере выполнения процесса на сервере клиенту отдаются кусочки такого кода:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
меняем значение прогресса
</script>
```

И в самом конце:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".inprogress").hide();
</script>
```

Суть в том, что коннект между сервером и клиентов не разрывается на время выполнения длительной операции, клиент все "ждет и ждет", а сервер понемногу выдает кусочки Javascript кода, который и отображает значения прогресса.

Конечно, в настройках php.ini max_execution_time должно быть достаточно большим, чтобы длительный процесс успел закончиться.